# Number of items in a table in dynamodb using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to get the number of items in a table from dynamo db.

**Code**

```
def urlfn():
     if request.method == 'GET':
          print("GET REq processing")
          return render_template('index.html',count = table.item_count)
```

But I am not getting the real count. I found that there is a 6 hour delay in getting the real count. Is there any way to get the real count of items in a table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the row count of a table instantly in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378347/how-to-get-the-row-count-of-a-table-instantly-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 0):

assuming in your code above that table is a service resource already defined, you can use:

```
len(table.scan())
```

this will give you an up to date count of items in your table. **BUT** it *reads* every single item in your table - for significantly large tables this can take a long time. AND it uses read capacity on your table to do so. So, for most practical purposes it really isn't a very good way to do so,

Depending on your use case here there are a few other options:

1. add a meta item that is updated everytime a new document is added to the dynamo. This is just document of whatever hash key / sort key combination you want with an attribute of "value" that you add 1 to every time you add a new item to the database.
2. you forget about using Dynamo. Sorry that sounds harsh, but DynamoDB is a no-sql database and attempting to use it in the same manner as a traditional relational database system is folly. # of 'rows' is not something that Dynamo is designed for because thats not its use case scope. There are no rows in Dynamo - there are documents, and those documents are partitioned, and you access small chunks of them at a time - meaning that the back end architecture does not lend itself for knowing what the entire system has in it at any given time (hence the 6 hour delay)

Comment: Quick remark: DynamoDB is rather a key-value store. Another kind of "no SQL" database type.

DynamoDB maintains a total count of items. Unfortunately not accessible from the API, probably because it is just indicative (updated only periodically). A scan can be faster if filtering only on what to count.